# Why One Way Association can't use?

Tags: associations, sails.js

wateline version: 0.10.0-rc6

sails.js version: 0.10.0-rc4

sails-mysql version: 0.10.0-rc5

User.js

```
{
    info:{
        model:'userinfo'
    }
}
```

console output `Error: Trying to access a collection userinfo that is not defined.`

Comment: What does your `UserInfo` model look like?

Comment: I think One Way Association don't need edit UserInfo for use, like [sails beta document](http://beta.sailsjs.org/#!documentation/reference/ModelAssociations/OneWayAssociation.html)

Comment: Right, but do you *have* a UserInfo model?

Comment: yes, I user `sails generate api userinfo` create it, but I don't know this model name is all lowercase or must to **userInfo** for create?

Comment: If I use `sails generate api userinfo`, model name is `Userinfo`, so I use the `model :'userinfo'` to call.

Comment: Yup, that all sounds right.  When are you actually getting the error?

Comment: `verbose: Starting ORM...`